# PHP switch statement not working with == 0

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm working on a php project, but my switch statement is not working and I don't know why.

```
$status = 0

switch ($status) {
  case ($status == 0) :

    echo "0";
  
  break;
  case ($status == 1) :

    echo "1";

  break;
}
```

But this will output 1, not 0.
I've looked everywhere but couldn't find an answer that works.

Comment: The case line would be. `case 0:` and `case 1:`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: I've tried that, but that still won't work

Comment: you're missing a semi-colon in your first line - then you need to fix the code as per @JasonK

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$status = 0;

switch ($status) {
  case 0:

    echo "0";
  
  break;
  case 1:

    echo "1";

  break;
}
```

Comment: I know this is just a rip off of the comments above to try and get some reputation points, but I admire the tenacity so I've upvoted it